# I don't understand the definition of completion of a $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

I am preparing for the test there is a question that I dont understand: suppose that $(\Omega,\mathscr F,P)$ is the probability space where $\Omega:=\{1,2,...,6\}$, $\mathscr F:=\sigma(\{2,4,6\},\{1,3,5\})$, $P(\{2,4,6\})=0$. What is the $P$-completion of $\mathscr F$?

Comment: Do you know the definition of completion?

Comment: I wouldn't say this question is not constructive, neither I think it shall be closed for any other reason. And finally, it's actually asked by a newcomer, so we may be milder to him

Comment: @Eulunder, please click `edit` to see examples of how to use math formulas, and don't forget to answer the question of Chris Eagle.

Comment: I am trying to click edit but its not active

Comment: @Chris Eagle, I know the definition but I don't know how to apply it to this question

Answer (score 6):

**Hints**:

1. $P(\{2,4,6\}) = 0$, and $P(\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}) = 1$ since $P$ is probability. What does this say about $P(\{1,3,5\})$?
2. What are the $P$-null sets of $\mathscr{F}$?
3. List all the subsets of the sets given in part 2.
4. By definition, the completion of $\mathscr{F}$ relative to the measure $P$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing all of the subsets given in part 3 as well as $\mathscr{F}$. So what is this new $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: I'm failing to use the maths formulas but the answer to number 1. is zero

Answer (score 0):

The completion of the $\sigma$--algebra $\mathscr{F}$ defined above is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by
$$\mathscr{F}\bigcup\big\{\{2\},\{4\},\{6\},\{2,4\},\{2,6\},\{4,6\}\big\}$$

The $\mathbb{P}$-null sets are those listed between brackets.